# MasterDetail OSX app with a SourceView in View-Based mode

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I'm struggling to setup the correct bindings to make a SourceView (OutlineView) in View-Based mode to work with a TreeController. It does work correctly in Cell-Based mode.

Unfortunately I can't find how to setup header&title text, all I get is empty stuff :≤≤

What I get :

[image]

XCode project if you feel like digging in :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qz3m9p5vd2qvngb/MasterDetail.zip

Took the data from another post :

```
[
    {
        "itemName": "Item 1",
        "children": []
    },
    {
        "itemName": "Item 2",
        "children": [
            {
                "itemName": "Item 2.1",
                "children": []
            },
            {
                "itemName": "Item 2.2",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "itemName": "Item 2.2.1",
                        "children": []
                    },
                    {
                        "itemName": "Item 2.2.2",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "itemName": "Item 3",
        "children": []
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement at least the `-outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:` so the Outline View knows how to display the data. In your outline View datasource, implement the method like this:

```
- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item {

    NSView *cellView = [outlineView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"DataCell" owner:self];
    return cellView;
}
```

If tested this is your project and now the cells are displayed. Look at the `NSOutlineViewData` / `NSOutlineViewDelegate` Protocols for further informations.

Comment: I thought the purpose of bindings was to get rid of delegates? But that worked when adding a delegate to the `NSOutlineView` (in this case `AppDelegate`) & implementing your method.

In my case, the `dataSource` is a generic `TreeController`.